# cannot pass a literal constant in Matlab Coder

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm using Matlab Coder to generate C++ code. It gives an error at the last line in the shown code:

```
function [Xs Ys]=sc(X, Y, r)
...
xGauss=gausswin(2*r+1,5));
```

It would be fine if it's something like

```
xGauss=gausswin(11,5));
```

So I tried 2 ways, one is

```
xGauss=coder.const(@gausswin,2*r+1,5);
```

But it says "coder.const is undefined". Another way is to put coder.Constant on the variable r, but it failed again. On windows, it's "The 'coder.Constant' class does not support code generation." On Linux, it's " coder.Constant is not a supported enumeration. For code generation, enumerations must inherit from 'int32' or 'Simulink.IntEnumType'." How can I solve this?

Comment: `coder.const` was added in MATLAB release R2013b so that may be why it is not found. If you're using a newer version, that may signify an installation issue. `coder.Constant` is meant to be passed as an input to the `codegen` command rather than used in your code generation MATLAB code: `codegen sc -args {1,1,coder.Constant(5)}`

Comment: you are probably right, mine is R2011b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replacing gausswin with

```
function w = gausswin_2(L, a)
N = L-1;
n = (0:N)'-N/2;
w = exp(-(1/2)*(a*n/(N/2)).^2);
end
```